# In tables should date/time/year in table be left or right aligned?

Tags: tables, data-tables, dates, alignment

I would like to know whether the date/time/year should be right or left aligned in data tables/table?

Some articles mention right align, while some left align.

Is there any standard followed similar to text and numeric data alignment?

Reference articles:

- https://www.darkhorseanalytics.com/blog/clear-off-the-table/
- http://www.conetrees.com/2014/05/articles/data-tables-cell-content-alignment-usability-guidelines/

Comment: As long as a date is recognisable and readable within the context of your table, I don't think it matters.

Comment: I'd say right-aligned so that your years will still line up in year 10000. ;)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**Dates (in any format) should ideally be left-aligned** inside a data table column.

A rule of thumb is: [integers should be right aligned](http://www.briancoydesign.com/data-tables-cell-alignment/), while other types of data should be left aligned.

The default alignment for most types of data is left alignment -- this helps make the data easily scannable, readable and comparable.

Integers however may be more easily compared by right-aligning. For example, it is easier to quickly identify larger vs. smaller sales figures in a column when those figures are right-aligned.

Comment: Great reasoning

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer posted by Michael isn't incorrect, there's some things you should keep in mind in terms of readability.

> A rule of thumb is: integers should be right aligned, while other types of data should be left aligned.

This also accounts for dollar symbols and such. If you have a column that displays prices, try to maintain the spacing for the cents. You can do exactly the same for dates. In my example I have used months as a word instead of number, but this might vary on your user base. Keep your spacing consistent, make it easy to scan over, ensure the user knows what the month is (USA uses a different format than most of the EU, etc). **Do not let your user lose their time over something they have to double-check.**

Your links aligned the date to the right as they contain integers. Although I could argue to align all/most content the same, as it might ruin some of the readability if numbers and letters get pushed together on the same column separator.

(Image attached with an example of focus points in tables)
[image: Table with rules applied]

> TLDR;
>   **make sure your table is readable and understandable**

**DO**

- Same-space words and numbers
- Make the date format clear (let the user pick it or display it)

**DON'T**

- Have the user lose time because they are uncertain about date format and have to double check
- Have the user lose time because they can't read fast due to cluttering of words and or numbers
- Have the user lose time